# Limit of key emission per document in a CouchDB/PouchDB view

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a database structure like:

```
{_id: 'record/1', name: 'Record 1', labels: ['label/1', 'label/2', 'label/3'], created: '2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
{_id: 'record/2', name: 'Record 2', labels: ['label/1', 'label/5', 'label/7', 'label/3'], created: '2015-03-06T00:00:00.000Z'},
{_id: 'record/3', name: 'Record 3', labels: ['label/2', 'label/3', 'label/4', 'label/5'], created: '2015-03-10T00:00:00.000Z'}
```

I have a map function that emits multiple keys per document, i.e. for 'record/1', these keys will be emitted:

```
[2015,3,1] for record/1
["label/1"] for record/1
["label/1",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
["label/1","label/3"] for record/1
["label/1","label/3",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
["label/1","label/2"] for record/1
["label/1","label/2",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
["label/1","label/2","label/3"] for record/1
["label/1","label/2","label/3",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
["label/2"] for record/1
["label/2",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
["label/2","label/3"] for record/1
["label/2","label/3",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
["label/3"] for record/1
["label/3",[2015,3,1]] for record/1
```

It looks like **a lot of complex keys to be emitted per document**, but it supports the query requirements I have:

1. Find records created between a *start date* and an *end date*

   - `{startkey: [2015, 3, 1], endkey: [2015, 3, 9]}`
2. Find records applied with *multiple labels*, i.e. 'label/1' and 'label/3'

   - `{key: ['label/1', 'label/3']}`
3. Find records created between a *start date* and an *end date* and applied with *multiple labels*

   - `{startkey: ['label/1', 'label/3', [2015, 3, 1]], endkey: ['label/1', 'label/3', [2015, 3, 9]]}`

**Question**: With this approach, will I hit any limit or performance issue in CouchDB or PouchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this looks like probably the most efficient way to use map/reduce indexes in PouchDB. :) Putting everything into one big index will definitely get you the best performance during view building.

Comment: Thanks man, do you know if there is any documentation to back this?

Comment: I wrote most of PouchDB's map/reduce code. :) So I'm telling you based on my mental model of how it works.

The only case where your "one big index" might not be the most efficient is if you have, say, a tiny index that you need *right now* as well as a bigger index that you don't need until later. If you make two separate views/ddocs, then PouchDB can parallelize that and the smaller one can complete sooner. (Unlike CouchDB, it parallelizes all views, even views within the same ddoc.)

Comment: I see. That sounds great.